# Drag and dropping images between panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create two panels using jQuery [UI layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/) plugin, and then being able to drag & drop images between the two panels, on the right, the dropped image should maintain the position where it was dropped (and be able to drag it and keep the position anywhere on that right panel), then when drag & dropping from right to left panel the image should align like the originals.

This is the code im working on https://jsfiddle.net/Lwbka9ww/4/:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Layout Container</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="external/layout/layout-default.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        background: #666;
        width:      100%;
        height:     100%;                   
        padding:    0;
        margin:     0;
        overflow:   auto; /* when page gets too small */
    }
    #container {
        background: #999;
        height:     100%;
        margin:     0 auto;
        width:      100%;
        max-width:  1200px;
        min-width:  700px;
        _width:     700px; /* min-width for IE6 */
    }
    .pane {
        display:    none; /* will appear when layout inits */
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/layout/jquery.layout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#container').layout({
            west: { size: "20%" }
        });

        var $left = $( ".ui-layout-west" ), $right = $( ".ui-layout-center" );

        $( ".ui-layout-west .drag" ).draggable({
          cancel: "a.ui-icon", 
          revert: "invalid",
          containment: "#container",
          cursor: "move",
          helper: function () { return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex',5).show(); }
        });

        $right.droppable({
          accept: ".ui-layout-west .drag",
          activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".accept").append(ui.draggable);
            $(ui.draggable).css("position", "absolute");
          }
        });


        /*$( ".ui-layout-center .drag" ).draggable({
          cancel: "a.ui-icon", 
          revert: "invalid",
          containment: "#container",
          cursor: "move",
          helper: function () { return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex',5).show(); }
        });

        //$( "li", $('.ui-layout-center') ).draggable();

        function imageDropped( $item ) {
          $item.fadeOut('fast', function() {
            var $list = $( "ul", $right ).length ? $( "ul", $right ) : $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo($right);
            $item.appendTo( $list ).fadeIn('fast');
          });
        }*/
    });

    </script>

<style>

.drag {
    cursor: move;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="pane ui-layout-center">
        <div class="accept"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-west">
        <div class="drag">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" /> 
        </div>

        <div class="drag">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKDplYgDLBnlw0jBK06LriNY4eTqQtsf25U5VV95zAJBB9EavVhQ" /> 
        </div>

        <div class="drag">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-uqB0D8Xnjcao1kZ0W2P-uftmFxJlq6fTATe0YCJX3tdFaL8H" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My main problem is keeping the initial position and maintaining drag changes on the left panel, I haven't worked on right to left drag & drop yet.

Comment: do you want it to be in any place or horizontally above each others ?

Comment: Any place inside the right panel, no restrictions there.